# excel - advanced vlookup or other formula?

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding excel and I am looking for a formula that can help me transport my data from one sheet to the other. I have some experience with excel, however I am not a pro at it, so I apologize if this is a very trivial question but would also be happy since that would mean it probably has a very trivial answer! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points yet to post images, but I will try to explain it as clearly as possible.

Basically I am creating an excel template and the goal is to have 2 sheets in excel.

In the first sheet I have a column with following input in rows A1 - A3: Sales Region,
Country, Account ID's.

Above is the example of column A; from column B --> x; I will put e.g.

Americas, US and as many account numbers as there are in that specific country.

However on the second sheet it gets a bit complicated. My goal is that all the account numbers from sheet 1 **irrespective of their sales region and country** (which also means irrespective of their column) will automatically be listed on the second sheet.

The second sheet will be organized in the following way:

From column A - C; sales region, country and account ID.; from column D - x financial information for each account.

As a first step I want all the different account ID's from the different columns on the first sheet to be listed under column C (account ID's) on the seconds sheet.
As a second step I want column A - B to be automatically filled out according to account number by accessing the information in which column and thus sales region and country the account is in on sheet one.

I don't think a simple vlookup would do the job, especially for step 1, since I want the account ID's from many different columns and rows in sheet 1 to be listed in just one column....

hope it is clear enough! Would appreciate any help! :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first step take all of column A and copy it to the 2nd sheet on column C.
Select data ribbon and select remove duplicates.
For column A insert vlookup for column C for all the data in 1st sheet
For column B insert vlookup for column B for all the data in 1st sheet
Those value will work well only if an ID has one valid Region and country.
Now just use custom sort to sort it in the way you desire.

Comment: I am afraid that will not work, since the account numbers are not filled in on sheet 1 yet. I am basically trying to format empty sheets and then if someone fills in an account number in sheet 1, make that account number automatically appear in sheet 2 and copy the respective location specific information next to it.

Comment: You can use a macro to do so and active it when arow is added to the first sheet.